# What is the Command Line Parser package from Nuget "types" argument expecting?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I can't find any useful documentation or examples that seem to use the same version as I am, which requires this argument. Currently I have defined a class containing my arguments:

```
public class CmdArgs {
    // Required
    [Option("ifp", HelpText = "Input filepath", Required = true)]
    public string path_csv_in {get; set; }

    [Option("ofp", HelpText = "Output filepath", Required = true)]
    public string path_csv_out {get; set; }

    [Option("dfp", HelpText = "Deck filepath", Required = true)]
    public string path_deck_in {get; set; }

    [Option("ffp", HelpText = "Fortran .dll filepath", Required = true)]
    public string dll_path {get; set; }

    [Option("gfs", HelpText = "Gas fuel spec", Required = true)]
    public string path_gas_fuel_spec {get; set; }

    [Option("lfs", HelpText = "Liquid fuel spec", Required = true)]
    public string path_liq_fuel_spec {get; set; }

    [Option("dut", HelpText = "Driven unit type: PG or MD", Required = true)]
    public string type_du {get; set; }

    [Option("mgr", HelpText = "Main gearbox ratio", Required = true)]
    public string ratio_gb_main {get; set; }


    // Not required
    [Option("cts", HelpText = "CT capacity scale factor: Default is ..", Required = false, Default = ..)]
    public string ct_scale_f {get; set; }

    [Option("ipl", HelpText = "Inlet pressure loss, nominal: Default is ..", Required = false, Default = ..)]
    public string plin_nom {get; set; }

    [Option("epl", HelpText = "Exhaust pressure loss, nominal: Default is ..", Required = false, Default = ..)]
    public string plex_nom {get; set; }

    [Option("bpl", HelpText = "Exhaust pressure loss, bypass: Default is ..", Required = false, Default = ..)]
    public string plex_bp {get; set; }

    [Option("aef", HelpText = "Alternator efficiency", Required = false, Default = ..)]
    public string effic_alt {get; set; }
}
```

an object initializer:

```
CmdArgs ops = new CmdArgs();
```

and the parser:

```
Parser.Default.ParseArguments(args);
```

Some examples only seem to use the 'args' argument, but running with these arguments in the 'debug: command line arguments': (Paths and parameters replaced with generic paths etc)

```
-ifp "ifpPath" 
-ofp "ofpPath" 
-dfp "dfpPath" 
-ffp "ffpPath" 
-gfs "gfsPath" 
-lfs "lfsPath" 
-dut "duType" 
-mgr "gearboxRatio" 
-cts "ctScale" 
-ipl "inletPressureLoss" 
-epl "exhaustPressureLoss" 
-bpl "bypassPressureLoss" 
-aef "alternatorEfficiency"
```

throws 'Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name: types', and the tooltip when entering arguments into 'ParseArguments' states that it expects args, and 'params Type[] types', but what is this? I can't find anything useful or get my head round it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change the line

```
Parser.Default.ParseArguments(args);
```

into

```
Parser.Default.ParseArguments(args, ops);
```

You have to specify *into* where those arguments should be parsed.

**EDIT** Although, looking into it further, the above is for a previous version (1.9).

According to [the docs](https://github.com/commandlineparser/commandline) for the current version (2.2), you should do something like this:

```
CommandLine.Parser.Default.ParseArguments<CmdArgs>(args)
  .WithParsed<CmdArgs>(opts => RunWithOptions(opts));
```

where `RunWithOptions` is a method that you defined that runs the "real" code (and accepts a filled `CmdArgs` object as parameter).

Something like:

```
private static void RunWithOptions(CmdArgs options)
{
   // use the "options" to perform the real work
}
```

Comment: That gives me:
'Error CS1503 Argument 2: cannot convert from 'Performance_Agent.CmdArgs ' to 'System.Type'

Comment: So to just run my Main method I would replace RunOptionsAndReturnExitCode(opts) with Main(new string[] {opts.arg1, opts.arg2} etc)?

Comment: If you are already inside your Main method, that would lead to problems. Just move the "real" code (not the argument parsing) to another method and use that.

Comment: As in any part of the main method that contains the use of  a parsed argument should be moved to it's own method to be used here? Sorry for my lack of understanding, c# is all quite new to me.

Comment: Yes that is right. Your code contains two basic parts: reading the options and using them. The "reading" stays in Main, the "using" in its own method (that may call other methods) and gets the options through a parameter.